# Returning const std::string& vs const char* for class member

Tags: c++, string, member

Considering the following class example :

```
class AClass
{
    std::string myString;

    public:
    ...
}
```

With one of the following accessors :

```
const std::string& GetMyString() const
{
    return myString;
}
```

versus

```
const char* GetMyString() const
{
    return myString.c_str();
}
```

Taking into account that myString is initialized once and is never changed, which accessor is better? The first one, or the second one? In what situation  one of them is more suitable than its neighbor?

Comment: I would always do `std::string const& GetMyString() const` and never ever do `char const* GetMyString() const`.  YMMV.

Comment: Why not just return a plain `std::string` by value and keep things simple? Most likely, your micro-optimization here makes no actual difference in real life, but it complicates things needlessly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl really? is it that hard to return a const reference?

Comment: @Sopel of course it is not *hard to do*, but it has implications that returning by value do not. And unless OP is using this code in a *very* hot and performance critical loop, then it hardly matters performance wise, so there is *no need* to take on the extra complexity of a reference return value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl well, if you consider returning by reference ADDING complexity then I don't even want to argue further

Comment: @Sopel Yes, I do. You don't? I'd like to hear your arguments as to why returning by reference adds no complexity compared to returning by value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because it doesn't buy you anything. If you want a copy you can always make one. You don't buy time, because returning by const& should be the thing you consider along returning by value. You just waste time thinking if it's fast enough to copy or not. You waste time thinking how to make it as lazily as possible to please your misunderstanding of optimization principles.

Comment: @Sopel you are misunderstanding me completely. I'm not talking about optimizations at all. I'm talking about keeping semantics *simple* for the caller of the code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl so we're back again at the point that you think references are hard to understand

Comment: @Sopel I don't think they are hard to understand. But I do think they are harder to understand than value semantics. And when you don't *need* to use them you shouldn't. Unless you are just trying to make yourself look clever/smart (which usually results in you looking quite the opposite).

Comment: How about `string_view`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version returning `const std::string&` covers a superset of the use cases for returning `const char*` (after all, it can be converted to the latter by calling `.c_str()` on the return value), with no added weaknesses. Given that `std::string` is more flexible in other ways, I'd prefer `const std::string&` of the two options.

That said, they're both awkward if the owning object in question isn't immortal; even if the string is never changed, if the object itself disappears, the reference to its string is now invalid. If that's a possibility, you might want to either:

1. Return by value

or

2. Use a `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` member and return that (so the lifetime of the string is no longer tied to the lifetime of the object that created it)

Comment: Why complicate simple accessors. Just return the const&. There is no need to complicate the logic just because the caller may write bad code.

Comment: @Sopel returning by reference ties the lifetime of the returned value to the lifetime of the returning object (or to a temporary). This makes things harder to reason about for the caller. A simple return by value avoids all of that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If you know it returns A REFERENCE. And you assign it to A REFERENCE. And you DELETE THE PARENT OBJECT. And you use the value through this REFERENCE. Then maybe c++ is to complicated for such a person.

Comment: @Sopel we're done. If you decent to snide remarks like that, then I have nothing further to say. Have a nice day.

Comment: Does returning const std::string& implies issues for exported functions? e.g : different versions of STL